# CIImage Convert to UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, ciimage

I have one `UIImageView` I want to add one `CIImage` to my `UIImageView`
Here is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgimgurl: UIImageView!

imgurl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(slider.value), y: CGFloat(slider.value))
```

here is my convert code

```
imgurl.image = UIImage(CIImage: transformedImage)
```

but I received this error

**Ambiguous use of 'init(CIImage:)'**
**1. Found this candidate (UIKit.UIImage)**

Comment: Can you please show the code used to create `transformedImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will call init for resolve this issue

```
imgurl.image = UIImage.init(ciImage: transformedImage)
```